# PHP: Call Class' Static Method with Dynamic Class Name pre PHP 5.3

Tags: php, static-methods, legacy, dynamic-class

Im working on a project for a legacy codebase, using php 5.2.6. Part of this project involves something akin to A/B testing using one PHP class vs another. The two classes have many of the same function names, with very similar signatures, but different approaches within the methods. I am wondering if its possible to call static methods within the classes using a dynamic / variable-based class name.

For example, id like to set the class name as such:

```
$class = isset($some_condition) && $some_condition ? 'NewClassName' : 'LegacyClassName';
```

...and then call functions as such:

```
$class::myStaticFunction();
```

Im aware that this can be accomplished with call_user_func(), but Im having trouble finding alternative approaches (if there are any). I simply would rather not regex replace all the calls to the legacy class with call_user_func() statements.

e.g.,

```
$stuff = call_user_func($class . '::myStaticFunction()');
```

...does work just fine.

Does anyone know if there is a more simple way to express: $dynamicClassName::staticFunction() with PHP 5.2? Perhaps I am missing something with my syntax, etc.

Comment: You can upgrade your PHP version. Since 5.3 you can use they way you want to call your function. There is no other way in 5.2

Comment: The answer I feared! While thats what Id like to do, unfortunately, that isnt an option at this time. Feel free to answer with these comments and I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upgrade your PHP version. Since 5.3 you can use they way you want to call your function.

**There is no other way in 5.2.**

You can use this writing, maybe more easy to read :

```
$stuff = call_user_func_array(array($class, $method), array($arg1, $arg2));
```